# How to reuse JavaScript function for form input control?

Tags: javascript, function, input, onblur, onfocus

I have an input field that works exactly as I want it to, however, I have numerous fields repeating this same code.  Is it possible to call a JavaScript function and obtain the same results?

Here is my currently working html:

```
<input type="text" name="lname" value="Last Name" style="color:gray;" 
onblur="if((this.value == 'Last Name') || (this.value == '')) 
{this.value = 'Last Name'; this.style.color= 'gray';} 
else {this.style.color= 'black';}"
onfocus="if((this.value == 'Last Name') || (this.value == '')) 
{this.value = ''; this.style.color= 'gray';}
else {this.style.color= 'black';}"
onselect="this.style.color= 'black';"
onclick="this.style.color= 'black';"/>
```

But I was hoping to be able to do something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="lname" value="Last Name" style="color:gray;" 
onblur="onBlurAction()";
onfocus....
etc....
</input>

<script>
function onBlurAction()
{
    if((this.value == 'Last Name') || (this.value == '')) 
        {this.value = 'Last Name'; this.style.color= 'gray';} 
    else {this.style.color= 'black';}
}
function onFocusAction....
etc....
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function, `this` refers to `window` global variable, you should pass `this` as an argument:

`onblur="onBlurAction(this)"`

While the function(s) will be something like:

```
function onBlurAction(el)
{
    if (el.value == 'Last Name' || el.value == '') {
        el.value = 'Last Name';
        el.style.color = 'gray';
    } else {
        el.style.color = 'black';
    }
}
```

Another way is to not changing the function but use `onblur` that way:

`onblur="onBlurAction.call(this)"`

Comment: Ultimately I ended up passing two values into the function, i.e. 'onblur=onBlurAction(this, 'Last Name')"' and then accepted the string value in the function as an output value. This function can be reused simply by changing the second argument.  Thanks everybody for the help.  Since im new, I don't have a high enough reputation to up-tick.  Sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function as the handler for more than one event.

```
<input type="text" name="lname" value="Last Name" style="color:gray;" 
    onblur="onBlurAction();" onfocus="onBlurAction();" .../>
```

That will call `onBlurAction` for both the blur and focus events. You can do something similar for `onselect` and `onclick`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not use the [placeholder attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp)?

**Edit:**

Doing as Thomas Upton mentioned will not work because he is using the .value attribute. As soon as the user types something in, the value will change, therefore the function will not be able to check the (default) value correctly because it has been changed.

He could use the placeholder attribute instead to aid the function. Something like this:

```
        <input type="text" name="lname" value="" placeholder="Last Name" style="color:gray;" 
               onblur="javascript:onBlurAction(this.name);"
               onfocus="javascript:onBlurAction(this.name);"
               onselect="javascript:onBlurAction(this.name);"
               onclick="javascript:onBlurAction(this.name);">

               function onBlurAction(elname)
               {
                   value = document.getElementById(elname).getAttribute("placeholder");
                   if ((this.value == value) || (this.value == ''))
                   {
                       this.value = value;
                       this.style.color = 'gray';
                   }
                   else {
                       this.style.color = 'black';
                   }
               }
```

He passes the element name to the function and this function will get the placeholder value. This will work for all his text inputs reusing the function as he wishes.
Test here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/6qMj8/1/

Comment: This question is specifically about reusing a function for multiple events. While `placeholder` might actually work for this specific example, that's not a good general answer to this question.

Comment: I love the placeholder attribute, but there are still so many people using IE9 and earlier.  Is there a better way to implement the placeholder attribute for earlier versions of IE?

Comment: There are a number of `placeholder` polyfills [from Modernizr](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#web-forms--input-placeholder). A number of them require jquery, but there does appear to be at least one that's pure javascript.